# Can the command :filter be used recursively?

Tags: vimscript

I mean the `:filter` command, not the external one. 
I want to filter the filtered results again, if not clear.
The trivial try didn't work - `:filter /abc/ filter /cbd/ %list`

Answer (score 1):

As documented in [`:help :filter`](https://vimhelp.org/various.txt.html#%3Afilter):

> Only some commands support filtering, try it out to check if it works.

And that is followed by a list of "some of the commands that support filtering", which includes `:list` and about a dozen of others.

Even if the documentation mentions that list might be comprehensive, I think it makes a point that not all and actually not many commands support `:filter` and since filtering a `:filter` can be done in a different way (for instance, a regex using `\&` to match two separate patterns) I would expect such a feature wasn't really considered.

For your particular match, you can use:

```
:filter /.*abc\&.*cbd/ %list
```

Comment: yeh. I knew about the option to do \&. :g supports recursive behavior. Also in this case, it could have been done otherwise.